# Bootstrap justified nav not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a responsive navbar and I wanted to use something like this

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/

It is supposed to load like this
[image]

And when min-width reaches 768px it changes to this
[image]

But in my project it loads like this and it doesn't change at all

[image]

I used the styles from the example page (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css)

This is what's inside the body of my html

```
<header>
<a href="/index.html"><img id="logoss" src="images/logo.png"></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Empresa</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Medios</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Acci&oacuten</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Herramientas</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Staff-Sumate</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul></header>
```

and all of my style.css

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    background-color:#3b8476;
}

header {
    height:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color:#fff;
    background: #dddddd; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dddddd 0%, #ffffff 16%, #ffffff 82%, #dddddd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#dddddd), color-stop(16%,#ffffff), color-stop(82%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#dddddd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #dddddd 0%,#ffffff 16%,#ffffff 82%,#dddddd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #dddddd 0%,#ffffff 16%,#ffffff 82%,#dddddd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #dddddd 0%,#ffffff 16%,#ffffff 82%,#dddddd 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #dddddd 0%,#ffffff 16%,#ffffff 82%,#dddddd 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#dddddd', endColorstr='#dddddd',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

#logoss {
    height:8em;
    width:8em;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:2em;
}


/* from justified navbar example  */


.nav-justified {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.nav-justified > li > a {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  background-color: #e5e5e5; /* Old browsers */
  background-repeat: repeat-x; /* Repeat the gradient */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f5f5f5), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome 10+,Safari 5.1+ */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
}
.nav-justified > .active > a,
.nav-justified > .active > a:hover,
.nav-justified > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
.nav-justified > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.nav-justified > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-justified {
    max-height: 52px;
  }
  .nav-justified > li > a {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  }
  .nav-justified > li:first-child > a {
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  }
  .nav-justified > li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    border-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I just edited the post and added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something wrong with the version of bootstrap I'm using, I updated the file and worked just fine, thanks to everyone who tried to help